# Multiplayer game without code duplication on server and client

Tags: networking, websocket, server, client, multiplayer

I want to develop a very simple multiplayer game - just to understand the correct flow.
I want to implement an **authoritative server** with **web socket** of course, but I think I didn't understand the flow correctly.
For authoritative server we must save the whole game state in the server + all game logic, so that mean the actual game loop in running on the server.
So if a unit is moving right - it's happening in the server and we need to update the clients every millisecond.
It's sounds very bad method, so other options it's to duplicate the server main loop into the clients and run them both - while sends updates from the server, but it's sounds bad even more.
What i'm missing here?

Comment: "...and we need to update the clients every millisecond" - I think 60 frames per second is very high... even 24 frames per second (like the movies) is super smooth, so an update every 40ms is practically imperceptible. Also, the animation and the server don't have to match, a server could be updated every 0.5s (500ms) and the animation and gameplay will still rock.

Comment: Thanks. And do you think sending a message via websocket every 0.5s is ok? Is it a normal thing to do with websockets?

Comment: I think the question of message design is a great question... but it's not an SO question. The gaming or engineering communities might be a better fit. Moreover, it really depends on the game design. It could be a message per event (key up, key down) or a message per decision (go here). It also depends on the server's job (does it compute projectiles shot at the player's position? or maybe it's a quest type of a game)... these things can get complex very fast and it's often a good idea to delegate as much as possible to the client.